# Android : Soft keyboard is not showing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am creating a `Fragment` inside an `Activity`.I have an `EditText` in the `MainActivity` layout and the `Fragment` layout comes under that `EditText`.My issue is when I click the `EditText` the soft keyboard is not showing.

In `EditText` layout I create

```
 <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_searchContact"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_line_contacts"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:hint="Search..."/>
 <requestFocus/>
```

for showing the soft keyboard the code that I given in the `Fragment`

```
 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
 imm.showSoftInput(edt_searchContact, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

In Manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

I have 3 `Fragment` in one `Activity`,when one `Fragment` comes that `EditText` is going to Visible in main `Activity` layout.

Can anyone please help me 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Post your main activity code and your xml layouts as well. Where is the frame layout and how your replacing the fragments into the frame. Complete code, and i didnt get ur problem in the first case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your activity

```
editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_yourName);

            // Request focus and show soft keyboard automatically
            editText.requestFocus();
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

Comment: where should I get "getDialog()". In my activity I dont have a dialog box  @Akhil Jayakumar

Comment: sorry not getting. I put this code in my MainActivity after setContentView(R.layout.activity)

Comment: Yes I can  @ Akhil Jayakumar

Comment: you must use this LayoutParams 'import.android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;'

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                editText.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.showSoftInput(edt_searchContact, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        editText.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

On your Activity's onResume() Method you can write this:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
et.requestFocus(); 
InputMethodManager mngr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mngr.showSoftInput(et, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Comment: @BinilSurendran in Manifest write `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged"` , still if not then you can write `mngr.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);`

Answer (score 0):

The below method worked for me-

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
```